# Methods for constructing or checking for nontrivial classes in de Rham cohomology with local coefficients

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-group-theory

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold (possibly with boundary), $E \to M$ a flat vector bundle, and $\mathcal{L}$ the corresponding sheaf of parallel sections.

Given a de Rham cohomology class $[\omega] \in H^k(M; \mathbb{R})$ and a parallel global section $\sigma \in H^0(M; \mathcal{L})$, what methods can I use to check if the cohomology class (with local coefficients)  $[\omega \otimes \sigma] \in H^k(M; \mathcal{L})$ is non-zero?

If that is too broad a question, let's say that I start with a parallel global section $\sigma$ of my vector bundle and I wish to find a de Rham cocycle $\omega$ that will give me a non-trivial class $[\omega \otimes \sigma]$ in cohomology with local coefficients. I know in general this will not necessarily be possible to do, since the higher cohomology groups with local cofficients might vanish. But are there some heuristics I could use help me? For example, taking $\omega$ to be some non-vanishing Stiefel-Whitney or Pontryagin class, etc.

For example, if I understand correctly, I believe that in hyperbolic geometry we can use the Poincaré dual of a totally geodesic hypersurface to build degree 1 cohomology classes with local coefficients, at least for certain representations. I don't know if this works with totally geodesic submanifolds of other codimensions, but that would be nice if it did!

Apologies if this is a bit elementary; I'm not very experience with algebraic topology (though I'm reasonably familiar with category theory and sheaf theory).

Comment: If $\rho: \pi_1(M,x) \to GL(E_x)$ has finite image, or more generally if $\overline{\rho(\pi_1)}$ is compact, then the usual averaging argument implies that in fact there is a parallel splitting $E' \oplus \Bbb R \cong E$, the factor of $\Bbb R$ being spanned by $\sigma$. In particular, we have a splitting as $H^*(M;\Bbb R)$-algebras $$H^*(M;\mathcal L_E) = H^*(M;\mathcal L_{E'}) \oplus H^*(M;\Bbb R).$$ In particular, your map $[-\otimes \sigma]$ is injective. The geometric cases you're talking about are more interesting and are not captured by this comment.